# "eclipse is not installed" and "cannot execute binary file" while trying to install Eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation, eclipse

I installed [JDK 7](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html) default setting package from WebUpd8. I also installed [Ant 1.9.3](https://ant.apache.org/manual-1.9.x/install.html) which should be installed properly.

Firstly, I followed the instructions which I got from a google search; it said I just needed to download the package and extract it and put it anywhere I want. However, when I clicked Eclipse, it just doesn't work. Nothing happened.

So I did a lot of searching and I finally followed [this blog](http://ksearch.wordpress.com/2012/10/26/how-do-i-install-eclipse-juno-in-ubuntu-12-04/).

I downloaded Eclipse from the official site. Then I read its very neat instructions and compared them with many other instructions I found and it seemed like it should work. But after I followed all of those steps I got the message:

> "eclipse" is not installed

I read [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Linux_Example), then added the `-vm` and `/path/to/java` thing into the eclipse.ini like this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Then I tried to run Eclipse from the terminal again (with the command: `eclipse`) and got the error message:

```
nini@nini-Vostro-3350:~$ eclipse
bash: /usr/bin/eclipse: cannot execute binary file
```

I'm at a total loss. What should I do?

Comment: I don't really understand. Why didn't you install eclipse with `sudo apt-get install eclipse` ? Can you `cd` to `/opt/eclipse/` and simply enter `eclipse` in the terminal ?

Answer (score 1):

As of the link to the article you have mentioned in the question, the author shows an example to download 64-bit version of eclipse.

I doubt you are using x86 Ubuntu with a x86_64 JVM. To make sure your Ubuntu is 64 bits, run the following command:

```
$ uname -i
```

Comment: with this command i got: i386

Comment: i also tried the command "uname -mrsn" and got this output: 
"Linux nini-Vostro-3350 3.11.0-15-generic i686"
so i guess it's correct?

Comment: i686 that means you have x86 bit machine so try installing 32 bit eclipse

Comment: Thanks Aatish the 32-bit does work. sorry it was a stupid question :P but i still don't quite understand how come this cos actually all other apps and my OS are def 64-bit